# Filter argument in function that defaults to make dplyr::filter() filter nothing

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am building a function that imports excel spreadsheets.

I would like the function to include an argument that contains names of variables that the user is interested in seeing. The values from the argument is used in dplyr::filter() inside the function. I would like the default value of the argument to include everything (i.e. not filter anything away).

Libraries and Data:

```
library(tidyverse)
data("iris")
```

The filter function without any default filter values (this works):

```
FILTER <- function(data = iris,
                   Filter_Values) {
  data %>%
    filter(Species %in% Filter_Values)
}
FILTER(Filter_Values = c("setosa", "virginica"))
```

As written above, I would like the Filter_Values argument to default into NOT filtering anything.
This works, but is of course not general:

```
FILTER <-
  function(data = iris,
           Filter_Values = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")) {
    data %>%
      filter(Species %in% Filter_Values)
  }

FILTER()
```

Can you help me find a general term that can do the same. I have tried (and failed) with:

```
 Filter_Values = TRUE  
 Filter_Values = c(TRUE)   
 Filter_Values = regex(".*")
 Filter_Values = everything()
```

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Maybe `filter_if` and `filter_at` can help? Have you tried those?

Comment: `Filter_values = data$Species` ?

Comment: You could set the default value of `Filter_Values` to `NA` and have a test at the beginning of the function that replace `Filter_Values` by all values of the filtering column. You may also want to have an argument to explicit what column is the filtered column (here it's `species`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
FILTER <- function(data = iris,Filter_Values = NULL) {
    if (missing(Filter_Values)) data
    else data %>% filter(Species %in% Filter_Values)
}

FILTER()
```

Comment: Thank you. @Shinobi_Atobe solution works just as well for the above example, but this solution works better in my "real" function as the dataframe that needs filtering in that function is first created inside the function. With this solution I can apply the filtering function in the very end of the function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
FILTER <-
  function(data = iris,
           Filter_Values = unique(data$Species)) {
    data %>%
      filter(Species %in% Filter_Values)
  }

FILTER()
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesnt quite work for me. I see that my reproducible example is not good enough. The real function is called with a path to an excel file instead of data. So the dataframe that needs filtering is first created a way down in the function.

Comment: what about `str_extract(data$Species, ".*")`?